# Making a GWT app work on my mobile using phoneGap

Tags: gwt, cordova

When you create a GWT app you can run it as a web application and point your browser to the home page and it works.  Now, in this case your browser is being served the Javascript from the server and thus all calls to the server from your Javascript work fine. 
But,  if you then take the generated Java script and rather than have it server from the server just have it saved locally how would you go about getting your server calls to work.  Say your server is running on localhost how do you get this to work.  What I am trying to do is take a working GWT app and extract the generated Java script and wrap this in a phoneGap enabled app but I can't get my server calls to work.

Comment: Please post an update whether you were able to solve the problem. It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying adhoc approach. You should be looking at options provided by MGWT and PhoneGap - Reference http://www.m-gwt.com/.